# How can persist div overflow on scale

Tags: css, overflow, scale, scaletransform

In this [snipet](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FJCACYJRU14R)

I'm trying to persist the DIV visibility over other DIVs. On hover event, it scales-in the entire container but after  it return on the previous dimensions

[image]

Comment: What DIV are you talking about?

Comment: <div class="pin">

Comment: Do you want you it was scalable but disable transparency, right?

Comment: Please, form you thought better only then I will be able to help you

Comment: no actually. Transparency should be removed, that's not important.  I only need that on scale action, the pin zoom remains In. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FJCBTW01VJPQ

Comment: It seems only the first PIN  border remains shown on when scales

Comment: I don't understand you, sorry

Comment: I added a Picture

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. In my case, the pictures are placed vertically even when I scale my window.

Comment: You don't understand the issue **slesh**. When you hover over an image, it grows and parts of the image dissapears

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of fixing it by using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

I added the flexbox to the `#columns` id and used `flex-wrap:wrap`. Also added a `width` to the `.pin` class.

```
@media (min-width: 960px) {
    #columns {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: wrap;
    }
}

.pin {
    //other code
    width: 23%;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7zofwyau/5/

Comment: Thanks so much. your solution is great but I see that now Pins  has a fixed height at 510px , even  small pictures, so it  has no more "Pinterest" Effect.  and I see that there's a more blank space on the right side of the #Columns Element

Comment: the `height` changes depending on the resolution. For the gap on the right side, you can use `justify-content:center;` it will make the gaps equal. Not sure what you mean with the "pinterest" effect, though

Comment: pinterest effect is like placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space  https://pinterest.com/